# When giving Google Authentication a user-created password, what are the password requirements?

Tags: firebase, google-authentication

When creating a new user using Google Authentication in Firebase, what are the requirements for the user-created password? What is the character limit? Can the password contain unicode? Are there any encoding requirements, like ASCII only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All unicode characters are allowed in the passwords for email+password authentication in Firebase. There is no documented limit to the password length.

In the case where you use the Google authentication provider, Firebase has no knowledge of the password, so is not involved in its requirements.